# Process all .wav files in folder and append results to a single CSV file in Python 2.7

Tags: python, csv, audio, export-to-csv

I have 40+ .wav files in a folder at any given time. I need to compare each .wav file by doing a Power Spectral Density (PSD) analysis and spitting out the results into a one big CSV. Ideally each .wav file would have a column with its results... I've tried a number of different approaches on stackoveflow but can't seem to get the data for each .wav file to append to a new column. Instead, it appears to overwrite the previous results in the same column.

Ideally I would like the .csv layout to be similar to the following:
[image: csv layout]

Where each .wav file gets a column and has a header

Below is my simplified code, with the append to CSV portion completely not working.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
import csv
import glob
import os
import ntpath

csv_name = 'helloclay.csv'
path = r'C:\Users\Desktop\Spectral Work\Blacksmith'
csv_out = open(csv_name, 'wb')                   #Open CSV before loop so that all results will append to the same file
mywriter = csv.writer(csv_out)                   # create the csv writer object.      

    #start loop to process .wav files and write/append to csv
for audioFile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.wav')):
    #Extract Filename for Column Header    
    (fs, x) = read(audioFile)                     # sample rate & data
    basefilename = ntpath.basename(audioFile)     # pull filename from filepath    
    cutwav = len(basefilename)
    sig_name = basefilename[0:cutwav-4]           #remove .wav from basefilename to be used for csv_name
    cln_name = [sig_name]                         #change sig_name to array so csv will apply appropriate header

    #analysis portion
    (num_psd, freqspsd) = psd(x, NFFT=511, Fs=fs, pad_to = 1024)#PSD analysis
    psd2=20*np.log(num_psd)                       #Scale PSD to dB

    #write PSD to csv
    rows = zip(cln_name)                          #Write header to column
    mywriter.writerows(rows)   
    rows = zip(psd2)                              #Write PSD results under header
    mywriter.writerows(rows)

csv_out.close()
```

I've scoured through stackoverflow but all of the append to CSV document has to do with reading existing csv's and not creating a new one from newly processed data.

Any tips/help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you creating the `writer` inside the loop?

Comment: Path should be: `path = r'C:\Users\...'`

Comment: The csv file you're creating will have multiple header lines embedded within it, which isn't really proper in csv format files (although there's no [official standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), [RFC4180](https://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc4180.pdf) is the _de facto_ one). The latter says "There maybe an optional header line appearing as the first line of the file with the same format as normal record lines."

Comment: Your code appears to be trying to write a csv file with a single row of data in it, and that row is to have columns for every .wav file in it. Is that correct (and what really you want)? If not, describe (in your question) what you want the data layout to be.

Comment: @HaiVu what does including "r" do? it seems to work without it.

Comment: @martineau I tried to clarify the format that i'm aiming for. I understand this may not be the convention... but it's most convenient format for me at the moment. I will read RFC4180 when i get a chance. Thanks!

Comment: @jonrsharpe i wasn't quite sure where it should go. Judging by your comment, I imagine it makes more sense for it to go before the loop?

Comment: @ClaytonPipkin that would be more conventional, certainly!

Comment: @ClaytonPipkin The backslash is an escape character. It gives the next char a special meaning (e.g. **\n** is new line). To use it as a backslash, you will need to double it up (e.g `'C:\\Users'`) or to prefix the string with an **r** for raw string (e.g. `r'C:\Users'`)

Comment: To write a complete row of the csv file requires that the data for all the columns of that row is available at once, which implies that it's been determined for all the files involved already. There's no way to do that in a single `for` loop without generating/calculating it for all the files in parallel...and I don't see that happening in your latest code (unless I'm missing an important detail). You could do that separately by collecting the results incrementally, and then write that out to the csv all at once at the end. The only alternative would be to write the csv in multiple passes.

Comment: @martineau it seems that collecting the results incrementally would make the most sense.... though i'm not quite sure how i would go about doing that. Would you mind recommending some terms that i should search to learn how to do it?

Comment: Look for material about adding column(s) to csv files, which describes what needs to happen for you add the data for each .wav file to the csv file. Once that's figured-out, just do it for every file `glob()` returns and you'll have created what you want. Unfortunately this will require reading and rewriting all the rows in the output file many times in order to append new data to each one. It would be much more efficient to build a data structure in memory — like a list-of-lists — and the dump that to the file once at the end.